# Showing an internal log in an Android app

Tags: android

I want to show an internal log inside an activity. This log consists of text strings that inform the user about the status of an operation.

For example:

---

Process started

Doing task A

Doing task B

...

Process stopped

---

The only way that comes to my mind is to use a ScrollView with a TextView that will be updated whenever there is a new string in the log, but this solution seems inelegant.

Is there any UI widget that serves as a container for lines of text?

**EDIT:** I prefer not to use a ListView, I just want to show lines of plain text in a container, something simpler

**EDIT 2:** I used to develop Win32 programs in Delphi. There we have a TMemo component that serves as a container for lines of text. I'm looking for something similar in Android

Comment: Your question is subject to debate (see faq). Can you qualify what "best" is ?

Comment: ListView, but yeah this is a poor question, read a book on Android development?

Comment: @Reno, why is this a poor question? BTW, a ListView does not have the look and feel that I want. I'm not an Android expert, but I know the basics...

Comment: @Emmanuel, I will edit my question. Sorry, English is not my mother language

Comment: ... and I have read the FAQ. Will review it though. Thanks Emmanuel

Comment: How does the ListView not have the look and feel that you want? You can customize it quite extensively. If it truly doesn't, then please state what look and feel you *do* want.

Comment: @kabuko, I prefer not to use a ListView because I don't want a list with a highlight bar, just want to add strings one after the other, with an informative purpose and nothing more. I'll edit the question again to clarify things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's inelegant about updating a TextView? This is the most straightforward and simplest way to implement what you're looking for.

A TextView updated by a background polling event, probably by way of an Thread/AsyncTask is what I would try first. Don't confuse necessary complexity with inelegance. Sometimes the obvious first idea you have is the correct one.

Comment: This would also be much lighter on memory than creating individual TextView's and appending them to a container.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a vertical linear layout instead a `ScrollView`. Then just add `TextViews` to the `LinearLayout` as they are received. This would be more elegant that just appending the text items.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I forgot that a LinearLayout can scroll. But I don't want to dinamically add TextViews, I want something simpler. My question is not all that clear, I'm editing it now. Thanks